# Parametric Optimization In Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions

I want to solve the following problem:

$$ \max_q \dfrac{q}{a}\left[ (-\log(1-q))^{-a} - (-\log(q))^{-a} \right] $$ subject to $1\geq q \geq 0$ for each $a\neq 0$.

Here is the code I used:

```
Maximize[{(q ((-Log[1 - q])^-a - (-Log[q])^-a))/a, 1 >= q >= 0 && a != 0}, q]
```

Mathematica throws the problem back at me.

At first, I thought this was due to the parametric nature of the problem but then I tried to maximize $-(x-a)^2$ and it seems Mathematica can handle it.

Then, I thought maybe I should say it needs to be solved for each $a\neq 0$ so I tried

```
Maximize[{(q ((-Log[1 - q])^-a - (-Log[q])^-a))/a, 1 >= q >= 0 && ForAll[a, a != 0]}, q]
```

but this didn't work either.

I read that ParametricConvexOptimization in Mathematica but I want to be able to solve problems. Still, I tried to run it (without checking if my objective is concave) and as you can guess, it didn't work either. Here is my attempt at that:

```
OptQuant = ParametricConvexOptimization[-((q ((-Log[1 - q])^-a - (-Log[q])^-a))/a), {1 >= q >= 0, a != 0}, q, a]
```

Does anyone have any suggestion about what else I can try to solve this and other related problems?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You have two typos:  (1) $1\geq 1\geq 0 (which is inconsequential) and (2) `&& 1 >= q >= 0 && ` should be `, 1 >= q >= 0 && `.  Although fixing those two does not get you a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed these.

Comment: It appears that there is no maximum when $a>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to find the zero of

```
Reduce[D[q ((-Log[1 - q])^-a - (-Log[q])^-a)/a, q] == 0 && 0 < q < 1, q, Reals]
```

but it returns unevaluated, suggesting that there is no symbolic solution.  In the absence of a symbolic solution, a numeric solution can be obtained quickly with,

```
Plot[NMaxValue[{(q ((-Log[1 - q])^-a - (-Log[q])^-a))/a, 0 < q < 1}, q], {a, -1, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {a, max}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually played around with NMaximize as well but didn't get anything.

Would it be possible to get the argmax by this method? I am more interested in knowing the optimal $q$ given $a$ than the maximum level of the objective function.

Comment: @economicagent  Use NArgMax` instead. of `NMaxValue`.